# Lazy-Init based on a flag

Tags: java, spring

Here's my requirement:

At Spring context startup, I would like to call a method on my bean X. But the method call is dependent upon environment. One should be able to disable it. I am trying to use lazy-init function on the bean but unable to configure it so that the value is read from the properties file.

```
<bean lazy-init="${isEnabled}" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
```

But on context startup, Spring is unable to understand the `${isenabled}` flag. Is there an alternative way to configure this ?

Comment: Do you mean defining the complete lazy-init=false or lazy-init=true in the properties file ? If so, I tried that but it did not work.

Comment: @user451455 - this should work, are you certain that the properties file gets loaded? (another possibility is to use an environment variable)

Comment: The properties file does get load because I am invoking the method with parameters which are read from properties file.